# парсинг json в python

Tags: python, json

Парсю html, на странице ищу название и расширение файла

```
fr = requests('https://www.geooptic.ru/product/lasernyi-skanner-trimble-x7-kit-with-t10x').text
bb_strings = re.findall(r'files:.*.short_params', fr)
```

на выходе получается

```
fr = files:[{file_name:"obzor-skanerov-trimble.pdf",name:"Сравнение сканеров TRIMBLE X7, TX6, TX8 и тахеометра SX10 (2019 год)",type_id:eW},{file_name:"Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet.pdf",name:"Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet",type_id:4},{file_name:"Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12.pdf",name:"Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12",type_id:eW}]
```

как сделать что бы было?

```
Сравнение сканеров TRIMBLE X7, TX6, TX8 и тахеометра SX10 (2019 год) : obzor-skanerov-trimble.pdf
```

Comment: `files:` - у json ключи оборачиваются в кавычки, а то, что у вас больше похоже на синтаксис словарей javascript

Comment: Стек-трейс ошибки приводите полностью. Посмотрите, что у вас в `bb_strings[0]` когда ошибка выходит и нам тоже покажите.

Comment: @CrazyElf Возникло исключение: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: @gli9red теперь его ток через selenium распарить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @СергейКох что не так с кодом?

Comment: Я могу скопировать ваш код и вставить idle, чтоб запустить и  проверить?

Comment: @СергейКох исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как у вас в `bb_strings` получается список из одной строки, то можно её разбить по кавычкам, взять из неё нужные четные элементы, и затем собрать из них словарь.

```
import requests
import re


fr = requests.get('https://www.geooptic.ru/product/lasernyi-skanner-trimble-x7-kit-with-t10x').text

bb_list1 = re.findall('files:.*.short_params', fr)[0].split('"')

bb_list2 = [x for i, x in enumerate(bb_list1) if i % 2]

bb_dict = {}

for i in range(0, len(bb_list2), 2):
    bb_dict[bb_list2[i + 1]] = bb_list2[i]

print(bb_dict)

----------------------------------

{'Сравнение сканеров TRIMBLE X7, TX6, TX8 и тахеометра SX10 (2019 год)': 'obzor-skanerov-trimble.pdf',
 'Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet': 'Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet.pdf',
 'Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12': 'Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12.pdf'}
```

Как еще вариант -  двумя регулярками добыть нужные подстроки и затем сразу собрать из них словарь.

Comment: круто очень, если сделать через json? {file_name:"obzor-skanerov-trimble.pdf",name:"Сравнение сканеров TRIMBLE X7, TX6, TX8 и тахеометра SX10 (2019 год)",type_id:eW},{file_name:"Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet.pdf",name:"Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet",type_id:4},{file_name:"Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12.pdf",name:"Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12",type_id:eW} как его распарсить? или лучше новый задать вопрос?

Comment: @primmais Эта строка похожа на json, но не он. https://www.json.org/json-en.html